# Singleton and Instruments

Tags: objective-c, singleton, design-patterns

I've been trying to implement a singleton for shared data in an iPhone app, and I've used both the macro found here: 
[link text](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html)

and I've tried transplanting the code from the macro to straight .h/.m files and I can Build and Debug just fine, but once I try to run instruments I get an immediate crash with no helpful information (before the app even launches).

Is this common? Is it possibly not the singleton doing it (thought it seems like it started right when I added the singleton, there were some other app changes in there as well between runs, I think)? Does anyone else have any problems in xCode 3.1.2 running instruments using the singleton macro or direct code to that effect?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: I'm using some singletons in my app and can still use Instruments. Which instrument are you using exactly?

Comment: Turn on all warnings (with -Wall -Werror).  Turn on zombies.  Give us a crash report to work with.